Paying Extra thinking it goes to principle but it doesn't
I have a high interest loan and I am trying to pay it off asap. My Monthly payment is 571.00. I pay 175.00 a week. I always thought the extra would go toward the principle but they put it toward future payments and the interest. So I may be Months ahead in payments! Below is part of their contract that says yes, extra does go to the principle but they don't! Am I missing something here or am I looking at a good reason to hire an Attorney?

INTEREST BEARING LOAN. I agree to pay to the order of Lender,
Principal, plus interest ("finance charges") on the daily unpaid
Principal balance computed at the Contract Rate, in the Payment
amounts shown in the TRUTH IN LENDING DISCLOSURES on page 1 hereof,
plus all other fees, charges, and other amounts due under this
Agreement, at Lender‘s address set forth in this Agreement, unless
otherwise notified, until paid in full.
“All payments will be applied in the following order: (a) other
charges provided for in this Agreement or otherwise allowed by law,
and late charges; (b) interest accrued to the date the payment is
received and applied by Lender; and (c) if there is any remainder of
the payment, the unpaid Principal balance.”
Interest on my loan accrues daily on the unpaid Principal balance. If I pay early, more of my payment will be applied to the unpaid Principal balance. If I pay late or miss payments, more of my payment will be applied to interest. This will delay my Principal reduction and cost me more in interest. The Payment Schedule assumes that I will make each payment on the day it is due; therefore, my final payment will be adjusted as appropriate to reflect any variation in the actual dates my payments are received by the Lender. If any unpaid amounts remain due to Lender after my final scheduled payment due date, I agree to pay interest on these unpaid amounts, computed at the Contract Rate, until paid in full, to the extent permitted by applicable law.


Have you asked the bank?

The Manager said I have to call when I want to make a "Just Principle payment" but that isn't what the contract says. I emailed her and she demands I call? I have an automatic payment each week and don't think I should have to call.

Their systems may not be set up to apply multiple partial-month payments. Are they applying the extra each month to principal or not applying it to principal at all? Meaning, if you make 4 weekly payments in a month, does all 750 get applied eventually or just 571, and the remaining 179 applied to future payments?

"I have an automatic payment each week and don't think I should have to call. " They may not understand what you're trying to do. You shouldn;t have to call every week, but I think it's worth a phone call just to explain what you're doing and see how they can accommodate it.  Paying multiple partial payments is unusual so they may just need to manage your loan differently

179 to future payments so I am paid ahead. So now, I owe nothing for August so you would think at least 4 payments would go to principle. Nope, it begins to pay Septembers or Octobers. They are not a bank btw, it's OneMain.

"They are not a bank" - doesn't matter - they have computer systems that apply payments the way they've been programmed to and may not be set up to handle multiple partial payments (which is very uncommon for an installment loan) correctly by default.

In my experience, most banks apply overpayments directly to the principle. However, they may offer that method but default to the "advance due date" method. One credit union I use, does both. Overpayment is applied to principle but it also advances the due date since I'm technically ahead of the amortization schedule.
You need to call the customer service line and tell them that overpayments should not advance the due date and should be directly applied to principle.

It seems like you're expecting each weekly payment to have the accrued interest calculated and applied appropriately.  My guess is that their systems just aren't designed to handle this scenario.  It's unusual to receive multiple partial payments, so they may just need to set up your loan in their systems to handle them appropriately.
I would call them, explain what you're trying to do, and see if they can accommodate you.  If they can't, I would put the weekly payments in a separate account and just schedule one monthly payment from that account (the difference in interest paid will not be that much).

Am I missing something here or am I looking at a good reason to hire an Attorney?

I strongly doubt that the actual damages you would incur are worth hiring an attorney. The difference in interest between weekly and annual compounding is very small. Even with a 10% interest rate, paying monthly instead of weekly only reduces the effective APR interest by 0.03%, or $30 per year on a 100k loan.  With a smaller interest rate the difference would be even less.  It's not worth the hassle (in my opinion_ if you can still pay the loan off early by managing it slightly differently on your end.
It's great that you're trying to pay off the loan early by paying extra each month and fitting your cash flow better by paying weekly; the impact of paying extra each month will far outweigh the slight inefficiency of having to get it applied monthly instead of weekly.

You are far from the first to run into this.
Unfortunately, the default assumption by most banks is that if you pay extra you are prepaying to guard yourself against a missed payment in the future. If you want the extra to be used to pay down the principal instead, you usually have to say so explicitly on every payment you want treated that way.
I suspect that if you look at your loan agreement carefully you will find that this is, in fact, what it says -- though it may take some digging to find it. Banks are pretty darned careful about following agreements to the letter.
Frankly, the right thing to do right now is not to fight about it -- you won't win -- but to find out how far ahead you are and thus how many payments you can safely skip, use that to give yourself a short payment vacation if it's at least one full payment, and in the future to be very explicit about how much is loan payment and that the rest is to be used to pay down the principal. This may require two separate transactions, and may require writing two checks -- or actually going into a bank office to make the extra principal payment so you can talk to someone and make sure they understand and do it correctly -- unless the bank has an online payment mechanism that explicitly accounts for this.
You made a bad assumption. Not really the bank's fault you didn't check the procedure, and barely your fault since this rarely comes with clear instructions. It isn't the end of the world. Just correct it going forward.

A lot of good answers and I think the two payment idea is the best answer. Put the weekly payments into an account, have the autopay come from their side once a Month and then make the principle from mine, AND every few Months, have an 5 week Month to build a cushion...Thanks!!
